# Redirect user after first login in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

This code checks if a user is logging in for the first time, that is after registration. I want to redirect him to a custom page if so. Otherwise, redirect him to the homepage or admin page.

```
 function mylogin_redirect() {
    global $user_ID;
    if( $user_ID ) {
        $user_info = get_userdata( $user_ID ); 
        // If user_registered date/time is less than 48hrs from now
        // Message will show for 48hrs after registration
        if ( strtotime( $user_info->user_registered ) > ( time() - 172800 ) ) {
            header("Location: http://example.com/custompage");
        } elseif( current_user_can( 'manage_options' )) {
            header("Location: http://example.com/wp-admin/");
        } else {
            header("Location: http://example.com/");
        }
    }
}
add_action('wp_head', 'mylogin_redirect');
```

But it doesn't work? My guess is it doesn't get hooked into wp_head... 
I tried the following using login_redirect filter:

```
 function mylogin_redirect($redirect_to, $url_redirect_to = '', $user = null) {
    global $user_ID;
    if( $user_ID ) {
        $user_info = get_userdata( $user_ID ); 
        // If user_registered date/time is less than 48hrs from now
        // Message will show for 48hrs after registration
        if ( strtotime( $user_info->user_registered ) > ( time() - 172800 ) ) {
            return get_bloginfo('url') . "/custompage/";
        } elseif( current_user_can( 'manage_options' )) {
            return admin_url();
        } else {
            return get_bloginfo('url');
        }
    }
}
add_filter('login_redirect', 'mylogin_redirect');
```

Though it logs me in, it doesn't get me anywhere but to `http://example.com/wp-login.php` instead with a blank page.

**UPDATE:**
Ok, I don't know what's happening. Using the filter hook, I can get to the intended destination only after second login. Well not really second login but on the second click of the login button. I did it like so: enter credentials -> login -> (wrong page) -> hit back button -> enter credentials again -> login -> (correct page). Weird.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to adjust your filter call like so;

```
// filter name, callback, priority, accepted args
add_filter('login_redirect', 'mylogin_redirect', 10, 3);
```

Comment: Tried it, didn't work. It still redirects me to ../wp-login.php without the form. The problem with the filter is that the parser doesn't get into the `if` block. Because if I remove the `if` block and replace it with `return admin_url()` statement, it works fine.

Comment: You should be using the `$user` variable passed to the function - i.e. `$user->ID` instead of the global `$user_ID`.

Comment: That worked! But wordpress doesn't seem to recognize this `elseif( current_user_can( 'manage_options' )) { return admin_url();}` . Any idea? Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4492/how-to-use-current-user-can/4493#4493

Answer (score 2):

[Redirecting users on first login in WordPress](http://www.theblog.ca/wordpress-redirect-first-login): Cookie-based solution & User meta table based solution