# How to redirect after login to a particular page in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

I like to check if current user has access to read it. then open Particular Page.

in other word I want to redirect after login to a particular page in WordPress, and restrict other user to access to it.

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4267285/redirect-user-after-first-login-in-wordpress?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

[According to This article](http://www.theblog.ca/wordpress-redirect-first-login)

**Redirecting users on first login in WordPress**

On membership-based WordPress sites and other sites where you want to display a special welcome message or instructions to new users, you can implement some custom login redirect functionality. This functionality would kick in only once (or for the first few logins) per user.

The important elements on the code-side for such functionality is to use the built-in WordPress “login_redirect” filter, and to store information on whether or not the user has gotten the “first login” treatment. There are a couple of possible approaches to store the information, either in a cookie or in the user’s meta information (stored in the WordPress database in the “wp_usermeta” table).

Here is some sample code you can use in your theme’s functions.php file or in a plugin:

***Cookie-based solution***

```
// Send new users to a special page
function redirectOnFirstLogin( $redirect_to, $requested_redirect_to, $user )
{
    // URL to redirect to
    $redirect_url = 'http://yoursite.com/firstloginpage';
    // How many times to redirect the user
    $num_redirects = 1;
    // Cookie-based solution: captures users who registered within the last n hours
    // The reason to set it as "last n hours" is so that if a user clears their cookies or logs in with a different browser,
    // they don't get this same redirect treatment long after they're already a registered user
    // 172800 seconds = 48 hours
    $message_period = 172800;

    // If they're on the login page, don't do anything
    if( !isset( $user->user_login ) )
    {
        return $redirect_to;
    }

    $key_name = 'redirect_on_first_login_' . $user->ID;

    if( strtotime( $user->user_registered ) > ( time() - $message_period )
        && ( !isset( $_COOKIE[$key_name] ) || intval( $_COOKIE[$key_name] ) < $num_redirects )
      )
    {
        if( isset( $_COOKIE[$key_name] ) )
        {
            $num_redirects = intval( $_COOKIE[$key_name] ) + 1;
        }
        setcookie( $key_name, $num_redirects, time() + $message_period, COOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN );
        return $redirect_url;
    }
    else
    {
        return $redirect_to;
    }
}

add_filter( 'login_redirect', 'redirectOnFirstLogin', 10, 3 );
```

[Download the cookie-based redirect on first login plugin](http://www.theblog.ca/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/peters_redirect_first_login_cookie.zip)

***User meta table based solution***

```
// Send new users to a special page
function redirectOnFirstLogin( $redirect_to, $requested_redirect_to, $user )
{
    // URL to redirect to
    $redirect_url = 'http://yoursite.com/firstloginpage';
    // How many times to redirect the user
    $num_redirects = 1;
    // If implementing this on an existing site, this is here so that existing users don't suddenly get the "first login" treatment
    // On a new site, you might remove this setting and the associated check
    // Alternative approach: run a script to assign the "already redirected" property to all existing users
    // Alternative approach: use a date-based check so that all registered users before a certain date are ignored
    // 172800 seconds = 48 hours
    $message_period = 172800;

    // If they're on the login page, don't do anything
    if( !isset( $user->user_login ) )
    {
        return $redirect_to;
    }

    $key_name = 'redirect_on_first_login';
    // Third parameter ensures that the result is a string
    $current_redirect_value = get_user_meta( $user->ID, $key_name, true );
    if( strtotime( $user->user_registered ) > ( time() - $message_period )
        && ( '' == $current_redirect_value || intval( $current_redirect_value ) < $num_redirects )
      )
    {
        if( '' != $current_redirect_value )
        {
            $num_redirects = intval( $current_redirect_value ) + 1;
        }
        update_user_meta( $user->ID, $key_name, $num_redirects );
        return $redirect_url;
    }
    else
    {
        return $redirect_to;
    }
}

add_filter( 'login_redirect', 'redirectOnFirstLogin', 10, 3 );
```

[Download the user-meta based redirect on first login plugin](http://www.theblog.ca/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/peters_redirect_first_login_meta.zip)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help I really appreciate it.

How Can I  Assign One Page To user, in Management.

Comment: I want to creates private pages for each user. The content for that page is accessible on the frontend only by the owner of the page after he has logged in.

Comment: Its better to use plugins than you do it yourself. Check this link out https://wploop.com/specify-users-name-role-show-exclusive-content/

Comment: Thank you. You’re so helpful. I use this plugin, but how can i redirect after login to a particular page.

Comment: You can use Peter's Login Redirect to Define a set of redirect rules for specific users.

Comment: Ali is right, you can use the recommended plugin. see this link for more info http://tidyrepo.com/peters-login-redirect/

Answer (score 2):

**User Specific Content** is a great plugin that smoothly allows you to specify individual or groups of users, by role or user name, and give them access to specific content.

**Update** :
You can use **Peter's Login Redirect** to Define a set of redirect rules for specific users, users with specific roles, users with specific capabilities, and a blanket rule for all other users. Also, set a redirect URL for post-registration.